# How can I use std::decay when partially specializing a type trait?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits, partial-specialization

I made these type traits to determine if the type is a dynamic container, but recently ran into confusion when a reference to a vector didn't return true.

```
template<typename T>
struct is_dynamic_container
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T , typename Alloc>
struct is_dynamic_container<std::vector<T , Alloc>>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

I think I need to use `std::decay`, but I'm having trouble figuring out if it can be done like this rather than at the call site.

```
template<typename T , typename Alloc>
struct is_dynamic_container<std::decay<std::vector<T , Alloc>>::type>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

^^This doesn't work.

I just want to be able to write `is_dynamic_container<std::vector<int>&>` and not `is_dynamic_container<std::decay<std::vector<int>&>::type>`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<class T>
using is_dynamic_container_with_decay = is_dynamic_container<std::decay_t<T>>;
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepting this answer because it's the cleanest solution. Short and to the point.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
template<typename T,typename=void>
struct is_dynamic_container
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_dynamic_container<T,
  typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<T,typename std::decay<T>::type>::value,
  >::type
>
    : is_dynamic_container<typename std::decay<T>::type>
{};
```

---

If you don't mind an intermediate step, there is a simpler and more conservative solution. Rename `is_dynamic_container` to `is_dynamic_container_impl` and then

```
template<typename T>
using is_dynamic_container =
  is_dynamic_container_impl<typename std::decay<T>::type>;
```

Choose whatever is appropriate in your case.

Comment: Since C++14 you can use `decay_t`

Comment: @megabyde I'm aware of `enable_if_t` and `decay_t`, but the OP marked the question C++11.